# Accessing a MySQL db running in a docker container on Google Cloud VM Instance

Tags: mysql, docker, google-cloud-platform

I was looking for a VPS server to deploy my code to. My friend suggested using Google Cloud, so I signed up and started an Ubuntu VM instance, accessing from my Linux driven PC via ssh.

I started a Docker container with MySQL db on the instance, and I am wondering is it possible to access it from a different PC using for example DBeaver, and allow my GF to practice SQL. I couldn't find this particular info in the documentation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the goal is just to practice SQL, might it be easier to just start up a Cloud SQL instance? Then you don't need to worry about the layers of abstraction you've got going on with the container and the self-managed instance?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gabe. I think I wasn't thorough enough with the description of my situation. The practice will be on a database for my application running in a separate container. I will be able to develop my app, it will be served with proper data of the stuff we buy and it's expiry dates, and send emails when food is about to expire. Therefore we practice coding/querying, and less food gets wasted :) At somepoint I may want to migrate so I want to be able to clony a whole image of the OS with the apps and db's.

Comment: Got it, so the full deployment of the container is app + db + environ, but you want to open up the DB itself for your GF to practice raw SQL querying?

If that's the case, then it's a matter of opening a pinhole in the GCE instance's firewall. Confirm that's what we're looking for and I'll post an answer on how to do that.

Comment: Not sure if I understand it entirely, but it seems like so. I don't want her to go through all of the ssh-user-rsa-auth stuff on her Windows. Just do the queries on our app. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yup, so just e.g. be able to run `mysql -h <db IP> -u gf-user -p` and then start running the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our comments back and forth, what's being looked for is just gaining access to the DB from inside the GCE instance on which everything is running.

To do that, you'll need to open up a pinhole in the GCE's firewall (by default it blocks incoming traffic).

First step, is in the GCE instance, go edit it in the console, and scroll down a bit until you see the field for `Network tags` and put something in there specific...like "sql-testing" or something. This is so that you can apply the firewall rule ONLY to this instance and not all instances. If you're comfortable opening up access for all your GCE instances to your home IP address (I'm going the simple route to connecting, there are more secure and complicated ways to do this too) then you can skip this part.

Then head over to Firewall rules:
(https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list)

Click the Create Firewall Rule at the top.
Name it, then scroll down a little until you see "Targets" and more specifically "Target tags". In that target tags field, put in the tag you gave to your GCE instance. Or if you want it to apply to all your instances, then you can change the "Target" dropdown to "All instances in the network".

For the source filter, leave it on "IP ranges" and then get your home IP address and put it in the source IP range filter. It's CIDR notation, so just the IP address should be fine, or if you want to be super explicit, it would be `<IP ADDRESS>/32`.

For protocols and ports, you can either "Allow all" (easiest) or if you want to be really specific, you can do "tcp" and (we didn't talk about it, but if it's MySQL it's likely 3306, or Postgres it's likely 5432 unless you changed the port the DB is listening on).

Hit Create, and POOF you should have access to the DB using a db client.

Comment: You are a true mentor Gabe! Many thanks. Although I had issues with opening specific ports, allow all made me able to connect juts fine! So great you guys are monitoring SE, cheers!